# Insinuated gameObject won't get destroyed after OnCollideEnter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want `gameObject1` to get destroyed after it collides with `gameObject2`.

`gameObject1` is a non-kinematic rigid body and a nav agent with its destination being `gameObject2`, while `gameObject2` is an empty object. Both of them have box colliders, and neither has **Is Trigger** on. `gameObject1` succeeds in going towards `gameObject2`; however, they don't seem to be colliding. Instead of being destroyed, `gameObject1` doesn't stop moving. What went wrong?

```cs
void OnCollideEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "deleter")
    {
        Debug.Log("triggerdel"); //this doesn't show up on console.
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that your actual code? If so that’s the wrong method name

Comment: The method is called [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) ...

Comment: I'm more surprised that this is compiling

Answer (score 0):

Commenters have suggested using `OnCollisionEnter`, which is a Unity Message that is called whenever things collide. What you have now is not a Unity Message so it will never be called.

As an aside, it's a good idea to use `OnCollisionStay` instead. `OnCollisionStay` is called every single frame the object is being collided with, so in case of any bug the object will destroy in the next frame. `OnCollisionEnter` is only called for one frame, so if something goes wrong (which is very unlikely), the object will try to be destroyed again in the next frame.